# Swing JPanel With Buttons Cannot Repaint

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am currently building a simple minesweeper game for a school project, in which every field is an instance of the Field class which inherits JButton.
Here's (most of) the class in its current state:

```
public class Field extends JButton implements MouseListener {

    public Field() {
        super(" ");
        setFocusable(false);
        addMouseListener(this);
        setFont(new Font("sans serif", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        //...
    }

}
```

These fields then basically get added to a MineField object, which inherits JPanel. Here's the code for that, too:

```
class MineField extends JPanel {

    Field[][] fields;

    public MineField(int x, int y, int m) {
        fields = new Field[x][y];

        setLayout(new GridLayout(x, y));
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
                fields[i][j] = new Field();
                add(fields[i][j]);
            }
        }
        //...
    }

}
```

The size of the minefields are arbitrary, and are generated according the what difficulty the user chooses from the JMenuBar, with these methods:

```
    private void startBeginner() { startGame(8, 8, 10); }

    private void startIntermediate() { startGame(16, 16, 40); }

    private void startAdvanced() { startGame(16, 30, 99); }

    private void startGame(int x, int y, int m) {
        if(mineField != null) {
            remove(mineField);
        }

        mineField = new MineField(x, y, m);

        add(mineField, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // ...
    }
```

Most of what I created for now seems to work, with one exception. That being when I want to start a new game of the same difficulty of my current one. What happens is that all the fields disappear form the window, which has a blank MineField (although I'm not sure, that might not even be there, too). How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Use `revalidate` and `repaint` on the container you are changing to trigger a new layout and paint pass

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @MadProgrammer adding `revalidate` and `repaint` and removing `remove(mineField)` solves the issue of the container disappearing, but now the problem is that the previous container stays visible when a constructor of the container is called with different parameters. I could now solve this issue with a conditional, but a less crafty solution could be better if there exists one.

Comment: Don't keep creating a new instance of the MineField class. That class only needs to be created once and added to the frame. Then you have a method like `resetMineField(...)` that removes all the components and add them back based on the new game parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

When you want to remove the old board JPanel, and create a new one.
First, remote it by calling the container panel (its parent)

```
parent.removeAll()
```

Now, addyour new board JPanel to parent JPanel like you did:

```
parent.add(mineField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Then, by **using the JFrame** methods, refresh GUI by 2 methods one by one:

```
this.revalidate();
this.repaint();
```

Comment: Thank you! Works for me just fine. However, I had to use the `getParent()` method instead of `parent`